# How to write test case for below angular service

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have been trying to write Jasmine test case for below service function, but its failing, Please look in the code below, I have write it down a service "getAllNotificationList" take two parameters an nested array and a number and merge nested array data and create new data, which is working fine, trying to test same using test case and its failing.

Controller Code:

```
angular.module('mobilityApp')
            .service('manageNotifications', function(CommonDatahub, API_ENDPOINT, $window) {

            /**
             * @ngdoc function
             * @name getAllNotificationList
             * @method Of mobilityApp.service:getAllNotificationList
             * @description
             * prepare all notification list
             */
            this.getAllNotificationList = function(_arrData, _fmno) {
                var masterList = _arrData[0],
                        isUserList = _arrData[1].length > 0 ? true : false,
                        userList = _arrData[1].length > 0  ? this.convertArrToObj(_arrData[1]) : false,
                        allNotificationList = [],
                        count = 0;

                masterList.forEach(function(objVal) {
                    var obj = {},
                            listName = objVal['name'];

                    if( isUserList &&  userList[listName] !== undefined ) {
                        obj = userList[listName];
                        obj['elemPos'] = count;
                    } else {
                        obj['mobilityEventType'] = objVal;
                        obj['userPreference'] = true;
                        obj['fmno'] = _fmno;
                        obj['elemPos'] = count;
                    }
                    count++;
                    allNotificationList.push(obj);
                });
                console.log(JSON.stringify(allNotificationList));
                return allNotificationList;
            };

        });
```

Service Code:

```
   "use strict";

describe("ManageNotification API service test", function () {
  var manageNotifications, CommonDatahub;

  beforeEach(module("mobilityApp"));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_manageNotifications_, _CommonDatahub_) {
    manageNotifications = _manageNotifications_;
  }));


  var _fmno = 84194,
      _arrData = [[{
                    "mobilityEventType": "GENERAL",
                    "description": "Non Partner transfer created",
                    "defaultSelected": true,
                    "name": "NP_TRANSFER_CREATED"
                  }], [{
                    "id": 100000,
                    "mobilityEventType": {
                      "mobilityEventType": "GENERAL",
                      "description": "Non Partner transfer created",
                      "defaultSelected": true,
                      "name": "NP_TRANSFER_CREATED"
                    },
                    "userPreference": false,
                    "fmno": 84194
                }]],
      _allListData = [{
                      "mobilityEventType": {
                        "mobilityEventType": "GENERAL",
                        "description": "Non Partner transfer created",
                        "defaultSelected": true,
                        "name": "NP_TRANSFER_CREATED"
                      },
                      "userPreference": false,
                      "fmno": 84194,
                      "elemPos": 0
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 100000,
                      "mobilityEventType": {
                        "mobilityEventType": "GENERAL",
                        "description": "Non Partner transfer created",
                        "defaultSelected": true,
                        "name": "NP_TRANSFER_CREATED"
                      },
                      "userPreference": false,
                      "fmno": 84194,
                      "elemPos": 1
                    }];


  it('should merge master and user list and create new list', function() {
    var result = manageNotifications.getAllNotificationList(_arrData, _fmno);
    result.toEqual(_allListData);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test you have a spelling mistake:

```
result.toEqualt();
```

Remove the 't'.